# why Grep/egrep is not searching for 0 or more char "i" using * option?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

```
$ cat TestI

T I i ji ko kai

kji

li

ljsdi

kjdi
```

command

```
$ grep --color i* TestI
```

does not print anything, why ?

though `grep --color k* TestI` print what is should.

[image]

Comment: You should be using `grep --color 'i' TestI` OR `grep --color 'k' TestI`

Comment: You have a file in your current directory that starts with an "i"

Comment: It is working correctly in my system. The grep --color i* TestI prints the output of matching 0 or more chars i.

Answer (score 1):

You need  to escape special characters like * run it like this:

```
command $ grep --color i\* TestI
```

Comment: But i want to use the regular expression , * to find zero or more "i".

Comment: You can check the screenshot image i have added, it works as expected for k* but not for i*

Answer (score 0):

Use `.*` for wildcard rather than just `*`

```
grep --color i.* Test1
```

But as anubhava mentioned, is it safer to put it in quotes.

Comment: But this will search for i with any char, zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

It prints for me. I have copied your command in my system. Can you put a screenshot?

```
$ cat Test1
T I i ji ko kai

kji

li

ljsdi

kjdi


$ grep --color i* Test1
T I i ji ko kai

kji

li

ljsdi

kjdi


$ grep --color k* Test1
T I i ji ko kai

kji

li

ljsdi

kjdi
```

Comment: Hi,
i have added image link on description , please check

Answer (score 0):

You're doing two things slightly wrong here.

Point 1. The first is that you're not escaping the `*` in the `grep` argument:

```
% grep i* testfile
```

The shell will expand this `*` to any files in the current directory which start with an `i` (as @glenn-jackman commented).  That means (supposing you have files `i1` and `i2`, that the `grep` command will *actually* be

```
% grep i1 i2 testfile
```

...which will search for `i1` in the files `i2` and `testfile` – not what you want (do `echo grep i* Test1` to see what arguments `grep` is actually passed).

Point 2. If you instead gave the command as `grep 'i*' testfile` (so that the `*` isn't expanded by the shell, but passed to `grep`), then it *still* wouldn't work, since you're then searching for *zero or more* occurrences of `i`, and every line will match that:

```
% cat test.txt
Hello there
Line with one i and two ii
Another
% grep 'i*' test.txt
Hello there
Line with one i and two ii
Another
%
```

The first and third lines here do match the regexp, because a line with no `i` on it, matches ‘zero or more i’.

(The second point will also happen if you don't have any files which start with `i`, but your shell expands `i*` to exactly `i*` in that case)

If you actually want to search for lines with at least one `i` on them, then try `grep i testfile`; the searches `grep -E 'i+' testfile` or `grep 'ii*' testfile` would also work.

Comment: as you said "grep i* testfile"
will show all the file names starting from i,
but why "grep k* testfile" does not give the file name starting with "k", instead it is showing all the lines of file with 0 or more occurance of "k".
Please see the screenshot i have added in description (link)

Comment: Do you have any files in that directory starting with `i` or `k`? If you have a file `index.html`, for example, then `grep i* Test1` will expand to `grep index.html Test1`, which will search for `index.html` in Test1 (and not find anything).  If you _don't_ have any files starting with `k`, then `grep k* Test1` may expand (depending on the shell) to `grep k* Test1`, so grep will search for the regexp `k*`, and match on every line (because every line matches ‘zero or more k’). Putting quotes around `i*`, as in `grep 'i*' Test1` _prevents the shell expanding the *_, allowing `grep` to see it.